# I have a Nav Bar, with two issues, one comes with the other

Tags: html, css

Here is the Code also in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SgtRx/  (should done this earlier, sorry)

Okay, My navigation bar is within the Div Wrapper, underneath the header, and on top of the content area (body).

I'm a pretty novice user, so excuse any mistakes I may be making.

When I added *border* to separate each block (button or text) it separated the buttons well, however, it leaves a small whitespace at the end of the nav bar (the right-hand side).

The wrapper Div is 1000px and I have 5 buttons, each 200px, Therefore without borders they fit in perfect, but with the borders if I keep the width at 200px the nav bar moves down, and when I reduce the width of the nav bar, it leaves the white space on the right. I have been doing this for 2 days and i finally give in. Please Help if you can. Thanks.

```
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    header id="top">
    <div id="test">
    <img src="images/vintage.jpg" width="1000" height="605" table width="780" order="0"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"/>

    <nav id="mainnav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="noBorder" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="sightseeing.html">Sightseeing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eating Out</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What's On</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="noBorder1">Where to Stay</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav></div>
    </header>
```

And the CSS

```
    #mainnav ul {
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
margin-right: auto;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 25px;
    }
    /*This will style all links nested in the <nav> element with the ID mainnav*/
    #mainnav a {
width: 197px;
display: block;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background-color: #020202;
color: #FCFCFC;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
line-height: 290%;
border-radius: 0px;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: medium;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
margin-top: auto;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-left: auto;
opacity: 1;
    }
   .noBorder {

        border-left-style: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: please put your code in jsfiddle.net, if you do it you will get a better answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SgtRx/  Yeah so true, sorry, first time on here, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommand you to use **width:20%** for each button instead of using fixed value.

Same goes for the navbar, use **width:100%**

Answer (score 0):

This is your anserw:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/EHMq4/2/)

```
#mainnav a{
width:19.91%;
}
```

Comment: Hi bro, I done this, but all it does is fix the first issue, but than it leaves another issue of a white space on the right side of the navigation bar.

Comment: hi bro @user2479360, if you have other question ask it here, I will answer you, and if my answer is your favorite answer and is true tell me

Comment: Well my question is, once i make the change you suggested, it creates the issue of leaving a small white line on the right hand side of the nav bar, as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/T7pkG/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

- I used display flex on ul.
- Than set direct child **li** of **ul** ***flex:1**.
- Lastly, I set a tag to width:100%
- I have removed some unwanted code.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  color: #151515;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #250e20;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 1000px;
  min-width: 739px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  position: static;
}

#hero {
  clear: left;
  position: relative;
}

#hero img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2 {
  color: #3399cc;
  font-family: source-sans-pro;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 73px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#main {
  width: 58%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 34%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  clear: left;
  background-color: #02080a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 2%;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: static;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

figure {
  width: 420px;
}

figcaption {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

figure img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
}

.centered {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
}

.floatleft {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.floatright {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}


/*This will style links in all states*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 0px;
}

a:link {
  color: #ff6600;
}

a:visited {
  color: #ff944c;
}

a:visited {
  color: #ff944c;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: #f5f406;
  text-decoration: underline;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*This targets the unordered list nested inside the <nav> element with the ID mainnav*/

#mainnav ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
}

#mainnav ul>li {
  flex: 1;
}


/*This will style all links nested in the <nav> element with the ID mainnav*/

#mainnav a {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #020202;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: medium;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}

.noBorder {
  border-left-style: none !important;
}

#mainnav a:hover,
#mainnav a:active,
#mainnav a:focus,
#mainnav a.thispage {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #43a6cb;
}

#hero article {
  width: 36%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 43px;
  background-color: #d88673;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#hero h2 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}

#container {
  background-color: #e1e54e;
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 420px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

#prev {
  background-image: url(../images/larrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 420px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

#next {
  background-image: url(../images/rarrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 420px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

#slider {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 420px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
nav {
  display: block;
}

#test {
  height: 220px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  position: static;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="top">
      <div id="test">
        <img src="images/vintage.jpg" width="1000" height="605" table width="780" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" />

        <nav id="mainnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="noBorder">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="sightseeing.html">Sightseeing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Eating Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What's On</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="noBorder1">Where to Stay</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="hero">
      <div id="hero2">
        <div id="container">
          <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
          <div id="slider">
            <img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="1000" height="420" />
            <img src="images/slide3.jpg" width="1000" height="420" />
          </div>
          <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <article id="main">
      <h2>Riding the Cable Cars</h2>
      <p>No visit to San Francisco is complete without a ride on the iconic cable cars that climb up the vertiginous hills of the city. Of the twenty-three lines established between 1873 and 1890, three remain: two routes from downtown near Union Square
        to <a href="http://www.fishermanswharf.org/">Fisherman's Wharf</a>, and a third route along California Street.</p>
      <p>The cable cars rely on cables running constantly beneath the road&rsquo;s surface. The driver—or gripman—uses a lever to grip the cable to pull the car and its passengers up the hill. The gripman requires not only great strength, but also great
        skill. He needs to know where to release the cable to coast over crossing cables and points. The conductor works in close cooperation with the gripman, operating the brake at the rear of the car to prevent it from running out of control on the
        downward slopes.</p>
      <figure><img src="images/cable_car1.jpg" width="400" height="266" alt="" />
        <figcaption>The cable car terminus near Union Square</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p>Although the cable cars are now mainly a tourist attraction, they're still used by local commuters to get to and from work. The California Street line is particularly popular among commuters on weekdays.</p>
    </article>
    <aside id="sidebar">
      <h2>Cable Car Tips</h2>
      <p>A single ride on a cable car costs $6. If you plan to travel around the city, it's often cheaper to buy a <a href="http://www.sfmta.com/cms/mfares/passports.htm">Muni Passport</a>, which gives you unlimited rides on San Francisco's extensive public
        transport system, including the cable cars (but not the <a href="http://www.bart.gov/">BART subway</a> system). Even a single-day passport ($14) will save you money if you make a return trip, and stop off to visit Chinatown one way.</p>
      There are often long lines at the cable car terminus, particularly on the Powell-Mason and Powell-Hyde routes. If you don't want to wait, try walking a few stops along the route. The conductor usually leaves a small number of places to pick up passengers
      on the way. The California Street route is generally less crowded (but not as spectacular).
    </aside>
    <footer>
      <div id: "footer">
        <p>&copy; Copyright 2014 Bayside Beat</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```